# How to implement complete process of afterSave in to CakePHP 3.1.13

Tags: cakephp

When I'm saving data, data saved but after that `afterSave` function is not working.
How it works, can anybody explain in detail?

In controller,

```
$Product = $this->Products->newEntity();
$this->Products->save($ProductsEntity, array('callbacks'=>false));
```

In Model,

```
public function afterSave(Event $event, EntityInterface $entity, ArrayObject $options)
{
  ...Function not called
}
```

But it is not working...!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

afterSave event working properly, you just have to create function of `afterSave` and include(use) related classes,

`afterSave(Event $event, EntityInterface $entity, ArrayObject $options)`

and include `Event`, `EntityInterface` and `ArrayObject` classe,

Here is documentation : https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/table-objects.html#aftersave, Please review and implement properly.

Answer (score 3):

Make sure that you add the `afterSave` method to your `Table` class – not your `Entity` class.

Also, where is `$ProductsEntity` coming from and what is `array('callbacks'=>false)` about? There is no such option and if there was it would probably do the exact opposite of what you want.

See the available options here:
https://api.cakephp.org/3.1/class-Cake.ORM.Table.html#_save

Also note this one:

> If no changes are made to the entity when it is saved, the callbacks
>   will not fire because no save is performed.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you! Your suggestion is more useful.